# Blank PHP page on Apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am trying to migrate an OpenX adserver to a new server. Apache, MySQL and PHP are all installed, but when accessing the site from any browser, a blank white page is displayed.

I have tried putting a one-line .html file and a PHP file with phpinfo(); in it - both work just fine, the PHP file displays all relevant information, but the default administration login page doesn't load.

The file structure and the database were copied over from the previous server (where everything worked perfectly) and I have modified the Apache Virtual Server settings to have it show to the current directory where the files are located.

The OS on the new server is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

By default, PHP displays a blank page when an error occurs. Check your error.log or add the following to your PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: The Apache error.log has tons of errors like:

'PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method Net_IPV4::ip2double() should not be called statically in /var/www/adserver.ekomediagroup.ro/lib/pear/Net/IPV4.php on line 442'

with ipInNetwork and parseAddress appearing instead of ip2double.

Additionally, there are a couple of errors like:

'PHP fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object'

Comment: Calling non-static methods statically was [deprecated in PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php). It looks like your server runs a newer version of PHP than the application requires.

Comment: It is running 5.5.9. The old server might have been running an older version. Could simply reverting to that version solve the problem?

Comment: It would: reverting to any PHP version before 5.4 will fix it, but then you're working with unsupported versions. The best solution is to edit your php.ini and exclude E_STRICT warnings from the error reporting:
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

The reason is that by default, error reporting is set to E_ALL, however before PHP 5.4 the group E_ALL did not include E_STRICT errors.

Comment: I've checked the php.ini file, which currently has `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`, which would exclude these errors, although it does not. Anyway, wouldn't this only disable the error reporting? I'm more worried about the fatal error `Call to a member function query() on a non-object`.

Comment: The error points to a MySQLi object not being initialized properly. Is the application's querystring correct? Normally I'd say output the value of the MySQLi object, but this is not your own code of course.

Comment: Nope, I am just tasked with migrating the site from one server to the other. Strange thing is, the whole thing worked perfectly on the previous server, and no code was changed at all.

Comment: Could be an issue with your connect file. Ensure that the credentials are correct. i.e. servername, dbname, username, password

Comment: Database connection seems to be ok. Quick update: I have installed LAMP locally on my own machine and put a copy of the adserver there. When accessing it locally (127.0.0.1) the admin page loads, the server works fine - when accessing remotely, from a different machine, the blank page problem persists.

Comment: i don't know why dont i get any errors on screen by adding these line and also i have enable log_error in php.ini.